# Spring Boot import.sql encoding issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, utf-8, import.sql

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE, and when trying to use the import.sql file to add demo data with Arabic letters as follows:

```
INSERT INTO city (active, name_arabic,name_english) VALUES (b'1', 'الرياض','Riyadh');
```

The value is inserted in the database as : `Ø§Ù„Ø±ÙŠØ§Ø¶`

I tried adding the following to application.properties with no luck:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;autoReconnect=true;useSSL=false
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

The database I am using is MySQL and the collation is `UTF8_GENERAL_CI`.

This issue happens only when I run the project on server, if run a unit test or build the application with Maven the issue doesn't happen.

Comment: can you try with executing this `ALTER TABLE city CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` ?

Comment: Are your database and table set to accept UTF8_GENERAL_CI???

Comment: @harshavmb , yes the database and all tables are set to UTF8_GENERAL_CI

Comment: @YCF_L, same behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was solved by using the following maven plugin:

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
              <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the above plugin will solve encoding issue for **command line build**.

**UPDATE:** to solve the issue when you **run project on server**:

1- Run As

2- Run Configurations

3- Change the encoding for the server to be UTF-8 as in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` into db-url.

The error you were getting in your XML was most likely due to using '&' which is not an allowed entity in XML. You should definitely encode the connection, so the work connection url should be something like

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_Name?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

You can also make sure that your server is configured properly, for tomcat for instance adding URIEncoding to connector

```
<connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

will specify the character encoding used to decode the URI. You should find an equivalent for your server

Comment: i am not using xml, i am using application.properties and the spring.datasource.connectionProperties is equivalent to adding the properties to the db url

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for discussion of what causes it, and what needs changing in your code.

To further verify, do `SELECT HEX(...) FROM ...`; that string should have hex `C398C2A7C399E2809EC398C2B1C399C5A0C398C2A7C398C2B6`

If, instead, you get `C383CB9CC382C2A7C383E284A2C3A2E282ACC5BEC383CB9CC382C2B1C383E284A2C385C2A0C383CB9CC382C2A7C383CB9CC382C2B6`, then you have "double encoding".